# Java: Minecraft: Variable Type Conversion

Tags: java, variables, minecraft

I have narrowed down my problem to the following, I need to convert a String to a Item Identifyer.

Example:

```
String str = "pickaxe";
Item pick = str;
```

That would resolve to Identifying pick as pickaxe. How can you do this?

Comment: You have to be more specific to get a better answer. From what I understand do you need an enum?

Comment: is Item a class you wrote? sorry for that question but i don't know the minecraft-api. please tell us the package of Item if it's not your class

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is a [Hash Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

In your code you can create your objects

```
Item pickaxe = new Pickaxe();
Hashmap<String, Item> items = new HashMap<String, Item>();
items.add("pickaxe", pickaxe);
```

Then later you can retrieve your item with

```
items.get("pickaxe");
```

Comment: Would items.get("pickaxe"); return pickaxe as an Item?

Comment: If you create the object like I show at the start of the example. To be honest you haven't provided any real information. Are you using a minecraft API? Are you making a minecraft clone. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: using minecraft api and forge api

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would recommend an enum for this sort of string-to-Object lookup, but I also know that there's a huge list of items in minecraft that will change from game update to the next. That means that putting those [around 370 items](http://www.mmorpg-core.com/forum/minecraft/minecraft-item-id-list-27465.html) into an enum is a lot of work.

My suggestion: store them in a database or something else that is not your sourcecode. Then load it into a structure such as a HashMap or a List, the first one being easier for lookup up the short name, just as joey.enfield suggested. With a list, you would have to iterate through the whole thing to find an item with a matching name.

EDIT:

```
public enum Item {
  PICKAXE("pickaxe"),
  SHOVEL("shovel"),
  BOW("bow");


  private String m_shortID;
  Item(String shortID){
    m_shortID = shortID;
  )

  static Item lookupByShortID(String shortID){
    for(Item i:values()){
      if(i.m_shortID.equals(shortID)){
        return i;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. Im not doing all the items in Minecraft, just 20 or so. Could you elaborate on the enum?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty class I cooked up. You should be aware that this code will most likely produce a hashmap that does not contain EVERY item as there are most likely items that have the same String value for getItemDisplayName(), so the last one in Item.itemsList[] will be the one in the hashmap.  Also note that it will produce a different list if you use a different MC language since getItemDisplayName() gets the localized String.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

public class ItemListByString
{
    private Map<String, Item>       itemMap;
    private static ItemListByString instance = new ItemListByString();

    private ItemListByString()
    {
        itemMap = new HashMap<String, Item>();

        for (Item item : Item.itemsList)
            if (item != null)
                itemMap.put(item.getItemDisplayName(new ItemStack(item, 1, 0)), item);
    }

    public Item getItemByString(String s)
    {
        return instance.itemMap.get(s);
    }
}
```